# Setstate completes after even thou it's in a .then

Tags: reactjs

I'm very confused on this.  I know it has to do with the async nature but I'm not able to get this to function the way I need it to.
I need the firebase.set to run.  When that is completed then this.setstate to run, once that is completed the next then to run.

```
    .then(keyUid => {
      let updatedFamily = {...family, [keyUid]: [firstHousehold, lastHousehold, householdDropdown]};

      this.props.firebase.db.ref('organization/' + currentOrganization + '/members/' + keyUid ).set(
        {
            first: firstHousehold,
            last: lastHousehold,
            phone: phone,
            email: email,
            address: address,
            address2: address2,
            city: city,
            zip: zip,
            headOfHousehold: headOfHousehold,
          }, (error) => {
               if(error){
                  console.log(error);
               }
               else{
                    this.setState({ family: updatedFamily }, () => console.log(1));
                }
        })
    })
    .then(newHouseholdUid => {
      console.log(2);
      Object.keys(family).forEach(key => {
        this.props.firebase.db.ref('organization/' + currentOrganization + '/members/' + key ).update({
          family: 'howdly'
        })
      });
  })
```

Currently console.log(2) runs BEFORE console.log(1).  I would expect for this.setstate to resolve before it moves on to the next .then

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

React batches state updates for performance reasons.
In your case the state you are setting to updatedFammily, you can use a locally scoped object to get the intermediate results

```
  let res = {}
  ...


    .then(keyUid => {
  let updatedFamily = {...family, [keyUid]: [firstHousehold, lastHousehold, householdDropdown]};
  res.updatedFamily = updatedFamily;

  this.props.firebase.db.ref('organization/' + currentOrganization + '/members/' + keyUid ).set(
    {
        first: firstHousehold,
        last: lastHousehold,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        address: address,
        address2: address2,
        city: city,
        zip: zip,
        headOfHousehold: headOfHousehold,
      }, (error) => {
           if(error){
              console.log(error);
           }
           else{
                this.setState({ family: updatedFamily }, () => console.log(1));
            }
    })
})
.then(() => {
  console.log(2);
  Object.keys(res.updatedFamily).forEach(key => {
    this.props.firebase.db.ref('organization/' + currentOrganization + '/members/' + 
   key ).update({
      family: 'howdly'
    })
  });
  })
```

You can also use async await to get around this but that would require changing bit more,

Hope it helps

Comment: This wouldn't work because updatedFamily is nested in the firebase call no? In example when I console.log it it's undefined  @ibtsam

Comment: @FabricioG I have updated my answer for a work around please check